# How to apply styles in key-value pairs in DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Okay, let's say we create a DOM element:

```
let element = document.createElement('div');
```

Now, if I want to apply styles onto it, we can say:

```
element.style = 'display: inline-block; width: 50%; height: 100px; background: #f00;';
```

We can also say this:

```
elemenet.style.display = 'inline-block';
elemenet.style.width = '50%';
elemenet.style.height = '100px';
elemenet.style.background = '#f00';
```

This approach is way too much repetitive because you always have say `element.style.`, when you're applying multiple styles.

In jQuery-like syntax we can apply an object of key-value pairs in jQuery's `$.css()` method, like this:

```
$(element).css({
    display: 'inline-block',
    width: '50px',
    height: '100px',
    background: '#f00'
});
```

With that being said, we can say the following:

```
let styles = {
    display: 'inline-block',
    width: '50px',
    height: '100px',
    background: '#f00'
};

for(let property in styles) {
    if(styles.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        element.style[property] = styles[property];
    }
}
```

This will apply all the styles in the `element`. I could even write a function, let's say `applyCSS(element, styles)` and do the same thing as above.

But, in the last case, if we do the following:

```
element.style = {
    display: 'inline-block',
    width: '50px',
    height: '100px',
    background: '#f00'
};
```

This won't fly at all. This won't work at all and no styles will be applied to the element.

My quesion is: how to properly apply key-value pairs for `style` in DOM?

Comment: Do you want us to help you fix the issue in the last paragraph, or provide opinions on the 'best' method of achieving this??

Comment: `style` on HTMLElement is a non-configurable and non-writable value. So you cannot override it. You can only mutate it. So one of the way you mentioned should be used based on your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still mess with the `CSSStyleDeclaration` prototype to add your function. But I wouldn't do that without being extra cautious and add a lot of verifications that i didn't do here.

An example:

```js
CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.setStyles = function(styles){
  for(let property in styles) {
      if(styles.hasOwnProperty(property) && property in this) {
          this[property] = styles[property];
      }else{
          console.error('no property ' + property);
      }
  }
};

document.body.style.setStyles({
  color: 'red',
  foo: 'bar',
});
```

```html
<span>text</span>
```

**EDIT** changed CSS2Properties to CSSStyleDeclaration

**EDIT2** Added some other possibilities

You can also extend the `HTMLElement` prototype too, like this:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.setStyles = function(styles){
  for(let property in styles) {
      if(styles.hasOwnProperty(property) && property in this.style) {
          this.style[property] = styles[property];
      }else{
          console.error('no property ' + property);
      }
  }
};

document.body.setStyles({
  color: 'red',
  foo: 'bar',
});
```

```html
<span>text</span>
```

But the safest way would be to use your own HTML element class, a bit like jQuery does, and not mess with prototypes of important objects:

```js
function myHTMLElement(selection){
  //you can use this function as a selector like jQuery, testing the type of "selection" is a string and use querySelector
  
  var construct = function(selection){
    this._element = selection;
  };
  //defining it on prototype means all instances will use same function
  construct.prototype.setStyles = function(styles){
    if(this._element && this._element.style){
      for(let property in styles) {
          if(styles.hasOwnProperty(property) && property in this._element.style) {
              this._element.style[property] = styles[property];
          }else{
              console.error('no property ' + property);
          }
      }
    }
    return this;
  };
  
  return new construct(selection);
};

myHTMLElement(document.body).setStyles({
  color: 'red',
  foo: 'bar',
});
```

```html
<span>text</span>
```

Comment: I've got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: CSS2Properties is not defined˙` when running the snippet in Chrome, here on Stack Overflow...

Comment: @omerowitz you're right, that's the kind of caution I was talking about, should work better now with `CSSStyleDeclaration`

Comment: So, basically there's no way except prototyping the `setStyles` (or whatever) on the `CSSStyleDeclaration` object? A standalone function would not be possible I guess, except the one I wrote above...

Comment: A standalone function would be possible but it requires passing the element as argument like you did. You can also extend `HTMLElement`'s prototype too so you'd be able to call it directly on the element. The only alternative is to create your own element class that has these functions, a bit like jQuery does, and work with this class

Comment: @omerowitz added examples for the other possibilities

Answer (score 0):

probably with style property being treated as an object, it didn't let you assign a value for the property.

However, with `element.attributes['style'].value` it seems to work.

Precisely as below:

```
element.style = ''; //add the missing attribute
element.attributes['style'].value = 'display: inline-block; width: 50%; height: 100px; background: #f00;';
```

**Note that the style attribute is missing for the newly created element.**

Hope this helps.